# .addattachment not working with none standard file extensions

Tags: asp-classic, cdo.message

I have some code which sends emails out with an attachment.

```
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"  
Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 
Set cdoMessage = CreateObject  ("CDO.Message")   
With cdoMessage 
    Set  .Configuration = cdoConfig  
    .From = strEmail  
    .To = "address removed"   
    .Subject = "subject email"  
    strMessageBody = "<h2>Message</h2>"   
    .HTMLBody = strMessageBody  
    .AddAttachment (strFile)  
    .Send  
End With
```

Code works fine for attachments ending ".doc", ".xls" ".ppt", ".zip"

As soon as any "none standard" extensions are used, for example say ".msg" I get an error message:

"CDO.Message.1 error '80040218'

Unknown Error "

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: You can zip the attachment and send it zipped if everything else fails. :)

Comment: Any ideas how to do this on the fly, on a server I can't install any software on? I'm currently just validating to make sure no "rogue" attachments go through.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems sending attachments before using CDO. I solved my problems by specifing the correct encoding mechanism. You might need to do some experimentation. I successfully attach .pdf, .doc, .xls, .ppt files via asp classic and CDO.Message

e.g.

> myMail.BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "8bit"

[Reference available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526277%28v=EXCHG.10%29.aspx)